# Sql code: What does it mean

Tags: mysql, database, connection

I am a beginner at at this stuff. Could you tell me what is happening at each step of the code below. Thank you.

[image: code]

Comment: Please provide a code snippet here ...instead of providing image link

Comment: This looks like homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's connecting to a database, and executing a query.
1. Creating a connection. 
2. Opening that connection. 
3. Executing the sql query, command. 
4. Iterating through the results and printing the the values of the 'name' attribute.